# Confusing error with an if statement

Tags: javascript, regex, if-statement, greasemonkey

I have a Greasemonkey script that keeps track of different things on `unicreatures.com`.

One of the things I wanted to count was clicks on some links on the page, but not all links.

These need counted,
`http://unicreatures.com/explore.php?area=sea&id=89&key=bf12`
These should not be counted,
`http://unicreatures.com/explore.php?area=sea&gather=5&enc=394844&r=`

Someone helped me figure out a regexp that did what I wanted, but I had to code each different explore location (`area=**`) into it, so I decided that wouldn't work.

**The regexp version**

```
var links = document.getElementsByTagName( 'a' );

for ( var i = 0; i < links.length; i++ ) {
var link = links[i];
if ( /area=sea(?!\&gather)/.test( link.href )) {
    link.addEventListener( 'click', function () {
localStorage.steps=Number(localStorage.steps)+1
       // alert(localStorage.steps + ' in Sargasso' );
    }, true );
}
}
```

Obviously I don't want a billion if statements for the different values of `area=`, and I couldn't find a way to add a variable to a regexp.

**So I finally found some string manipulation commands and put together this:**

```
var url = window.location.href;
var startOf=url.indexOf("=")+1;
var endOf=url.indexOf("&");
var loc =url.substring(startOf,endOf);

var links = document.getElementsByTagName( 'a' );

for ( var i = 0; i < links.length; i++ ) {
var link = links[i];
if (url.indexOf("area=")>=0 && url.indexOf("gather=")<0) {
    link.addEventListener( 'click', function () {
localStorage.steps=Number(localStorage.steps)+1
localStorage[loc+"Steps"]=Number(localStorage[loc+"Steps"])+1
        alert(localStorage[loc+"Steps"] +" in local"+loc);
    }, true );
}
}
```

For some reason it counts even when the second condition is false.  Is this a simple case of me getting the syntax wrong somewhere, or is this a Greasemonkey bug?  I don't get any errors in the console.

Comment: Should not this be `url.indexOf("gather=")<0`?

Comment: actually you're right... I'll try that... but since it is supposed to return -1 and it didn't work even when it was `==-1` or `===-1` I don't know if it's going to help.... testing this darn script has had me collect at least 20 eggs I didn't want so far lol

Comment: @BGR Nope still counts egg clicks as well as steps... argggg, I changed that in my question though because that was a good point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try just to tweak your regexp version, instead of this:

```
if ( /area=sea(?!\&gather)/.test( link.href )) {
```

use this regex:

```
if ( /area=(\w*)&id=/.test( link.href )) {
```

that will match all links that have an 'area' parameter followed by an 'id' parameter, which seems enough to match the links you want.

Comment: Note that this answer also checks the regex against `link.href`, which I’m pretty sure is what OP wanted. Checking agains `url` will always, on any given page, give the same result.

Comment: url is a variable I defined, only way I could make the `indexOf()` work, is that not a valid variable name?

Comment: Thank you, that worked!!!  Although I still don't know WHY my other code wasn't working...  I'm still confused about regexp too... the site I looked at said `\w` matched any character... how are you guys getting it to match a word?

Comment: It took the other answer for me to get the whole `url` problem...  DUH!

Comment: Yes `\w` matches any character, so `/(\w*)&id=/` means match any characters **followed** by the text `&id=` , the links that dont match does it because don't have the text `&id=` after the area parameter.

Comment: If you're happy with the answer and solves your problem please mark it as ANSWERED and upvote it. Thanks! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Prefilter the links and test the **link.href**, not `url` -- which was set to the page's address by previous code.

```
var linksWithArea   = document.querySelectorAll ("a[href*='area=']");

for (var J = linksWithArea.length - 1;  J >= 0;  --J) {
    var link        = linksWithArea[J];
    if ( ! /gather=/i.test (link.href) ) {
        link.addEventListener ('click', function () {
            localStorage.steps          = Number(localStorage.steps) + 1;
            localStorage[loc+"Steps"]   = Number(localStorage[loc+"Steps"]) + 1;
            alert(localStorage[loc+"Steps"] +" in local"+loc);
        }, true );
    }
}
```

Comment: DUH! Why didn't I see that?!!! Yes, `url` was a variable I defined **with the page address!!!** So do I accept your answer or the other one since it pointed that out in the comments and I still didn't get it?!!

Comment: Upvote both and accept either one.  He needs the points more.

Comment: Thank you so much... ADHD stikes again